# Silverlight Smooth KeyDown Event

Tags: c#, silverlight, keypress, keydown

This question is basically the same as
[Silverlight keydown event for games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806377/silverlight-keydown-event-for-games)
but there was never really a clear answer.  How can I get smooth keypresses for a game.

Can I **check what keys are currently being held down** inside a timer? (My best idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given was correct, you can't detect the currently pressed keys.  However you can handle key down and key up on the form at the layoutroot element.  You can then build you're own class which tracks the currently pressed keys.  Simply add keys to a list whenever you get a key down event and remove them from the list when you get a key up event.  You can then use PressedKeys.Contains(MyKey) to determine if a key is pressed.

Comment: You will need to ensure that an element within layout route has focus for key presses to register, and therefore you'll need to handle gracefully the possibility of receiving a key down but no key up or visa versa.